# Find all solutions of $e^z = e$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we go about doing this?

$e^z = e \implies e^{x+iy} = e \implies x+iy =1$

Obviously $(1,0)$ works, but what else?

Comment: I guess nothing else

Comment: Hint: Think about $2\pi i$

Comment: The function $e^{z}$ is an $2\pi i$-periodic function: $e^{z}=e^{z+2k\pi i}, \;\;k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: If $e^z=e$ then $e^{z-1}=1$, so $e^w=1$ if $w=z-1$. Can you find all solutions of $e^w=1$?

Comment: Hint: $e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)=e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e=e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$$ Therefore considering modulus of both sides $$e=e^x,$$ and considering imaginary parts $$0=\sin y.$$  Hence $$x=1,\, y=2n\pi,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: I don't see how you deduced that $e = e^x$ from $e=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$ and why $\sin y = 0$

Comment: $e=e^x\cos y + e^xi\sin y$ so $Re(e^z) = e^x\cos y$, $Im(e^z)=e^x\cos y \implies e=e^x\cos y, 0=e^x\sin y \implies \sin y =0 \implies y = 2\pi k \implies x = 1\cos(2\pi k) = 1$  Thus $x=1,y=2\pi k$. So $z = 1+2\pi k i$

Comment: if we consider the modulus of both sides, we can obtain $|e^z|=|e^x(\cos y+i\sin y|=e^x\sqrt{\cos^2y+\sin^2y}=e^x$ and also equating imaginary parts of both sides gives $\Im e=e^x\sin y=0.$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that :$e^z = e = e^1 \iff z - 1 = 2n\pi i \iff z = 1 + 2n\pi i, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why is it the case that $e^z = e = e^1 \iff z - 1 = 2n\pi i$?

Comment: $\cos x = \cos 1 \iff x  = 1 + 2n\pi$

Answer (score 1):

$ e^z = e $ , z = x +i*y

=> $|e^z| = |e^{x+i*y}| = e^x = e $ => x= 1 (here the exponential is real, you have injectivity)

Now we get : $ e^z = e*e^{iy} = e $ => $e^{iy} = 1$ => $y = 2k\pi$ , k integer

Let: $z_o$ = 1 + $2ik\pi$ , $e^{z_o} = e^{1+2ik\pi} = e $

So all solutions are { 1+ $2ik\pi$ , k integer}